# Check if all values in array are true, then return a true boolean statement (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

I have an array of booleans, which begins as false, because at least one of the values is false:
**var validation = [false, true, true]**
In certain moment, it'll have all the options(index) as "true", like:
**validation = [true, true, true]**
How can I set this array as "true" when all the options are true?

Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: You could also use "some" for example: var arr = [true, true, true, true, true, true ];
var allTrue = !arr.some(x => x === false);
console.log(allTrue);

Comment: @darmis moreover `some` will be faster as it will stop as soon as it finds `false` - no need to check every item to see if they all `true`

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can use `.every()` method:

```js
let arr1 = [false, true, true],
    arr2 = [true, true, true];

let checker = arr => arr.every(v => v === true);

console.log(checker(arr1));
console.log(checker(arr2));
```

As mentioned by @Pointy, you can simply pass `Boolean` as callback to `every()`:

```js
let arr1 = [false, true, true],
    arr2 = [true, true, true];

let checker = arr => arr.every(Boolean);

console.log(checker(arr1));
console.log(checker(arr2));
```

Comment: Or simply `let result = arr1.every(Boolean);` - the Boolean constructor will return `true` or `false`.

Comment: `Boolean` means that it cast each array member into Boolean value right?

Comment: @buncis in short yes. `Boolean` is a built in function available that will cast its argument to corresponding boolean value when used without `new` operator.

Answer (score 37):

You can use this to check if every values in array is true,

```
validation.every(Boolean)
```

Comment: This would fail if it includes strings

`["FALSE"].every(Boolean)` would return true

Comment: @TOLULOPEADETULA That is expected. "FALSE" is a truthy value in JS. You cannot evaluate string values to false based on their content

Comment: `Boolean` means that it cast each array member into Boolean value right?

Answer (score 11):

You can check if array have "false" value using "includes" method, for example:

```
if (validation.includes(value)) {
    // ... your code
}
```

Comment: no this doesn't do justice for all values, it only check if one of the array value includes your value!

Comment: @Danish
if (!validation.includes(false)) { } for example.

Although .every() is much better!!

Comment: `includes` is definitely better because I believe `every` is ES6 and above, or just a very new feature. I don't use `includes` as often as `indexOf`, so I'll use that :)